# I would like to hide PHP GET-Names with a .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched for 3 hours now and could find specifically what I was searching for.

I would like to hide the name of the get variable from my address.
Means the part "?s=" or "&l=" should be hidden.

I've got a domainlink like this

```
domain.com/?s=name&i=24641&t=72471
```

and I would like it to look like

```
domain.com/name/24641/72471
```

Comment: The duplicate contains an extensive explanation of how URL rewriting works - so if you have not gone and tried to read up on it in detail yet, please do so. And then show us your attempt afterwards, and give a proper problem description along with it if you can't get it to work on your won. (A better one than "not working".)